# Reference request: about inverse Laplacian operator

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, laplacian

I am currently studying some problems about inverse Laplacian and the Yosida approximation and wishing to learn more about it.

Here is a [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1629349/the-inverse-of-laplacian-for-different-orders) about one of the problems that I am interested in.

> I am looking for a book which has some referece about how to transform
>   the inverse of Laplace operator into Fourier basis, in order to
>   compute $L^2$ norm. i.e.,
>
> $$ \|(I-t\Delta)^{-s}u\|_{L^2}^2=\sum_{k=0}?? $$ where $t$ and $s$ are
>   real numbers.

If you know there are some reference which has similar computation. Please kindly direct me there.

Thank you!

Comment: Expand $u$ in a Fourier sum (having the eigenfunctions of the Laplace operator with the appropriate boundary conditions as basis). Your operator is diagonalized and you can deal with it in the obvious way.

Comment: You can have a look in Brezis's book on Sobolev spaces, functional analysis and Pde, for example. It should be OK for you

Comment: the idea is that $(I-\nabla^2)^t$ is a convolution operator, hence it is diagonal in the Fourier basis, and $u \in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ is exactly the condition you need for $u$ having a nice Fourier transform; finally, the Fourier transform being an unitary operator on $L_2$, you get that your formula becomes much simpler in the Fourier domain

Comment: @user1952009 can you provide a reference about what you write? Maybe a book about this Fourier stuff?

Comment: Are you working in free space or in a finite region?

Comment: @TrialAndError I am working on a finite region, but I am only considering $u\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ now. i.e., for $0$ boundary condition.

Comment: Then I agree with the first posted comment.

Comment: @TrialAndError I am looking for a book which contains the things he points out.

Comment: Section 6.5 (Eigenvalues and Eigenfunctions) of Craig Evan's book on PDEs deals with elliptic problems (includes Laplace), and how you have an orthonormal basis of eigenfunctions that are highly regular.

Comment: @TrialAndError I am not sure this is what I wanted. I wish to have a reference for Fourier basis...

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thank you. I know Brezis's book, (have it right in front of me). But Brezis's book does not talk about Fourier stuff...

Comment: That's what an orthonormal basis of eigenfunctions is. It's a Fourier basis. Take a look at the theorems in the section of Evan's text that I mentioned.

Comment: @tankonetoone: Yes, it does. Look in the chapter about Hilbert spaces if you want (especially around something called "Hilbert basis"). Or follow the reference of TrialAndError.